# Add [] around numbers in strings

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7

I like to add [] around any sequence of numbers in a string e.g

```
"pixel1blue pin10off output2high foo9182bar"
```

should convert to

```
"pixel[1]blue pin[10]off output[2]high foo[9182]bar"
```

I feel there must be a simple way but its eluding me :(

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, there is a simple way, using [`re.sub()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.sub):

```
result = re.sub(r'(\d+)', r'[\1]', inputstring)
```

Here `\d` matches a digit, `\d+` matches 1 or more digits. The `(...)` around that pattern groups the match so we can refer to it in the second argument, the replacement pattern. That pattern simply replaces the matched digits with `[...]` around the group.

Note that I used `r'..'` raw string literals; if you don't you'd have to double all the `\` backslashes; see the [*Backslash Plague* section](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/regex.html#the-backslash-plague) of the Python Regex HOWTO.

Demo:

```
>>> import re
>>> inputstring = "pixel1blue pin10off output2high foo9182bar"
>>> re.sub(r'(\d+)', r'[\1]', inputstring)
'pixel[1]blue pin[10]off output[2]high foo[9182]bar'
```

Comment: Great but why does this not produce "... pin[1][0]off ... foo[9][1][8][2]bar"?

Comment: @SimpleSi: because The `\d+` matches as many digits as is possible; this is called *greedy* matching. If you used `\d+?` it would match as few as possible, or *non-greedy* matching.

Comment: I will read further -I'd previously used \d{1,} to find all the numbers - is that equally as valid as \d+ ?

Comment: Yes, `{1,}` has the same effect as using `+`.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`re.sub`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.sub) :

```
>>> s="pixel1blue pin10off output2high foo9182bar"
>>> import re
>>> re.sub(r'(\d+)',r'[\1]',s)
'pixel[1]blue pin[10]off output[2]high foo[9182]bar
```

Here the `(\d+)` will match any combinations of digits and `re.sub` function will replace it with the first group match within brackets `r'[\1]'`.

You can start here to learn regular expression http://www.regular-expressions.info/